# Cannot find module 'webpack'

Tags: angular, webpack

Decided to not to use the webpack for my project.   When I removed it from `package.json` getting below error on `ng s`.

> Cannot find module 'webpack'
>       Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
>           at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:609:15)
>           at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:535:25)
>           at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:663:17)
>           at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
>           at Object. (C:\AI Ops\Code\aiopsuidemo\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack\index.js:6:17)
>           at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:30)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
>           at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
>           at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
>           at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)

Could anyone please suggest what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular cli uses '@angular-devkit/build-angular' for building the project which has a dependency of 'webpack' (can be found in this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular. this might be the issue.

So, try `npm install` and then run `ng serve`.

Comment: problem resolved after execute npm install --save-dev webpack and npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server

Comment: I solved this problem by running: npm i vue-loader

Comment: I guess we don't use vue-loader in angular.