# ng build and ng serve not working due to "Could not find the implementation for builder"

Tags: javascript, angular, terminal

I am trying to run a project from github on my Mac.

When I run ng serve or ng build after `npm install` in the terminal in the correct folder I get the following error

`Could not find the implementation for builder @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server
Error: Could not find the implementation for builder @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server
    at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (/Users/x/x/x/Angular/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js:49:19)
    at ServeCommand.initialize (/Users/sydney/Downloads/HealthLock-Webapp-master/Angular/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:135:55)
    at async ServeCommand.validateAndRun (/Users/sydney/Downloads/HealthLock-Webapp-master/Angular/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command.js:127:9)
    at async Object.runCommand (/Users/x/x/x/Angular/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:178:24)
    at async default_1 (/Users/x/x/x/Angular/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js:32:31)`

I have followed all the information I could find based on other times this question has been asked here and on other websites. I have uninstalled and reinstalled. I have cleared the cache. I have tried `npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular`, `npm update`, `npm i --only=dev`, `ng update`. I have tried all the solutions I could find but none have worked.

Here is my versions:

```
 Angular CLI: 8.0.0

 Node: 12.3.1

 OS: darwin x64

 Angular: 8.0.0

 @angular-devkit/architect: 0.13.9

 @angular-devkit/build-angular: 0.13.9

 @angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.13.9

 @angular-devkit/build-webpack: 0.13.9

 @angular-devkit/core: 7.3.9

 @angular-devkit/schematics: 8.0.0

 @angular/cdk: 7.3.7

 @angular/http: 8.0.0-beta.10

 @ngtools/webpack: 7.3.9

 @schematics/angular: 8.0.0

 @schematics/update: 0.800.0

 rxjs: 6.5.2

 typescript: 3.4.5

 webpack:4.29.0
```

Here is my json file

```
 {
   "name": "x",
   "version": "0.0.0",
   "scripts": {
     "ng": "ng",
     "start": "ng serve",
     "build": "ng build",
     "test": "ng test",
     "lint": "ng lint",
     "e2e": "ng e2e"
   },
   "private": true,
   "dependencies": {
     "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
     "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
     "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
     "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
     "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
     "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
     "@angular/http": "^8.0.0-beta.10",
     "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
     "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
     "@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
     "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
     "angular2-signaturepad": "^2.8.0",
     "core-js": "^2.6.9",
     "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
     "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
     "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
     "lodash": "^4.17.11",
     "moment": "^2.24.0",
     "ng-circle-progress": "^1.4.1",
     "ng-select": "^1.0.1",
     "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.3.0",
     "ngx-device-detector": "^1.3.5",
     "ngx-mask": "^6.5.18",
     "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^0.1.2",
     "rxjs": "6.5.2",
     "rxjs-compat": "6.3.3",
     "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
          "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.9",
          "@angular/cli": "^8.0.0",
          "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.0",
          "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.0",
          "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
          "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
         "@types/lodash": "^4.14.132",
          "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
          "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
     "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
     "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
     "karma": "^4.1.0",
     "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
     "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
     "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
     "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
     "protractor": "^5.4.2",
     "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
     "tslint": "~5.9.1",
     "typescript": "^3.4.5"
   }
 }
```

Angular.json file

```
 {
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
   "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
     "healthlock": {
     "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "projectType": "application",
  "prefix": "app",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  },
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/healthlock",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/ngx-owl-carousel-o/lib/styles/prebuilt-themes/owl.carousel.min.css",
          "node_modules/ngx-owl-carousel-o/lib/styles/prebuilt-themes/owl.theme.default.min.css",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": ["src/env.js"]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "healthlock:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "healthlock:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "healthlock:build"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [],
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ]
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": [
          "src/tsconfig.app.json",
          "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
"healthlock-e2e": {
  "root": "e2e/",
  "projectType": "application",
  "architect": {
    "e2e": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
      "options": {
        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
        "devServerTarget": "healthlock:serve"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "devServerTarget": "healthlock:serve:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
        "exclude": [
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
    },
   "defaultProject": "healthlock"
```

Comment: Have you run `ng update`?

Comment: yes, I mentioned that in the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had the same issue on a few projects. I ran `npm i --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest` which seemed to fix everything for me.

**Note** - I have `@latest` at the end of my command which will install the latest version. At the time of me posting this answer, it installed version '0.800.3'.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: is there a way to have version 0.800.3 of @angular-devkit/build-angular installed but not have a dependency with webpack. like discussed here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54817008/cannot-find-module-webpack

configurations of v0.10.0 dont seem to require webpack

Comment: Thanks :) my issue got fixed with above solution

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an issue with the most recent release of the @angular/cli@8; This [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14082) could be related.  I suggest downgrading to @angular/cli@7 for the time being.

Comment: I have Angular CLI: 7.3.9 and Node: 12.3.1 and the error message is the same

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share your file: angular.json

You should have something like this inside architect :{..}

for ng serve :

```
...    
"serve": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "HealthLock-Webapp-master:build"
              },
              "configurations": {
                "production": {
                  "browserTarget": "HealthLock-Webapp-master:build:production"
                }
              }
            }, ...
```

and for ng build:

```
...
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/theme.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }}...
```

Comment: I added my angular.json

Comment: file looks correct! Don't know if you tried before: 1- **delete** nodes_modules 2- npm install  3- ng update @angular/cli @angular/core

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
npm uninstall @angular-devkit/build-angular
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular
ng update --all
```

Looks like you're using the old builders. In version 8 we update some of the internals of the CLI.